# React Draft JS get current selection (previous text block is being selected)

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I am trying to get current selection text or even block, I've found following code inside docs

```
var selectionState = editorState.getSelection();
var anchorKey = selectionState.getAnchorKey();
var currentContent = editorState.getCurrentContent();
var currentContentBlock = currentContent.getBlockForKey(anchorKey);
var start = selectionState.getStartOffset();
var end = selectionState.getEndOffset();
var selectedText = currentContentBlock.getText();
```

but `selectedText` is previous selected block meaning

block 1 (user clicks first time) 
block 2 (user clicks second time) 
it will show block 1 and then 
clicking block 1 (third time) will show block 2

it's like you have to double click to show correct block

any solutions to this? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was I was using previous state instead of latest state, this is working solution

```
const getCurrentBlock = (editorState) => {
    const currentSelection = editorState.getSelection();
    const blockKey = currentSelection.getStartKey();
    return(editorState.getCurrentContent().getBlockForKey(blockKey));
}

const getCurrentText = (editorState) => {
    const currentBlock = getCurrentBlock(editorState);
    const blockText = currentBlock.getText();
    return blockText;
}

const changeEditorState = (state) => {console.log(getCurrentText(state));}
```